# Usage of generics in Morphia

Tags: java, generics, morphia

Although I tagged this question as a Morphia issue, I think it's more general, but anyway, help is appreciated.

I have **IUser** interface that I don't have control over it:

```
public interface IUser<T> {
    ...
    public String getFirstName();
    ...
}
```

I, also, have an implementation **User** (Morphia entity) of this interface:

```
@Entity
public class User implements IUser<ObjectId> {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Property
    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
    ...
}
```

When Morphia asks for the classes to be mapped, I provide User.class, since this is the Morphia entity. Therefore, when I extend the BasicDAO, I provide **User** and **ObjectId** as types:

```
public class UserDAO extends MongoDAO<User, ObjectId> {
    public List<IUser<ObjectId>> getUsers(String id) {
        return ds.find(IUser.class, Mapper.ID_KEY, new ObjectId(id)).asList(); 
    }
}
```

Now, the problem appears in the **getUsers** method. As you can see, I want to continue working with the interface outside this class; that's why I expect `List<IUser<ObjectId>>` as a return type.

The first argument of the **ds.find(...)** method is a `Class<T>` type, so I provide IUser.class. But, because of this, I cannot anymore expect `List<IUser<ObjectId>>` as a result, but just `List<IUser>`. This way, I have lost the type of IUser. Is it possible at all to force this Morphia's method to return a list of parameterized IUser objects?

Thank you in advance,
Zlatko

Comment: Sure I will. I have only 4 questions asked previously without any clear answer or solution; that's why there was no acceptance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

What Guava, Guice and similar libraries do is accept a [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) which leverages an anonymous inner class to reify the types.  It would look something like this:

```
return ds.find(new TypeToken<IUser<ObjectId>>(){}, ...);
```

But obviously that's not really an option here since you can't change the library.  It is what I'd consider to be the correct solution however.

The second option is to just cast the class to contain the generic parameter.  This results in an unchecked warning however that needs to be suppressed or ignored:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"}) 
Class<IUser<ObjectId>> userClass = (Class<IUser<ObjectId>>) (Object) IUser.class;
return ds.find(userClass, ...);
```

### Edit:

It should really be noted that the suggestion above is really no better than just casting the entire list from a `List<IUser>` to a `List<IUser<ObjectID>>` before returning it.  Both carry the same need to suppress warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm interested in the second one, but, I get `Cannot cast from Class<IUser> to Class<IUser<ObjectId>>`. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Zlatko: Uh oh, looks like my IDE allowed it but the compiler doesn't.  That doesn't make it a very good suggestion!  You could always get around it by casting to `Object` first, but that's extra nasty.

Comment: Nasty, but it works! I will wrap this code in a common method since I need it in many places for different interfaces, so the important code will stay clean. Any additional suggestion is welcome.